# Opening multiple files, creating lists, and dictionaries with for loop and range function in iPython

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, range, ipython

I am trying to write a script that will take 10 data files, read them line by line making a dictionary of the first(gene) and third(value) item in the file, and then combine all of these into an output file with a 12th column showing the average among the 10 replicates. (I will be doing this for several different samples, each with 10 replicates.) I am trying to use a for loop and the range function to automatically generate the file names, dictionary names, etc. as I am pretty sure this is a cleaner way to do the job than writing out the the code to make the dictionary 10 times.  However, I am new to coding and I keep getting a "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call" on line 11 of my code ('gene{0}key'.format(i) = []) and I am sure it will do the same for several other lines of code that are structured the same way. If someone knows what I am doing wrong I would love to know what it is!  Thank you in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython

import re
import itertools
import numpy

sample = raw_input('sample: ')

for i in range(10):
    filename = sample+'_rand{0}.genes.tajD'.format(i)
    'gene{0}key'.format(i) = []
    'taj{0}value'.format(i) = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as data:
        for line in data:
            line = line.strip().split('\t')
            gene, taj = line[0], line[3]
            'gene{0}key'.format(i).append(gene)
            'taj{0}value'.format(i).append(taj)
    'dic{0}'.format(i) = dict(itertools.izip('gene{0}key'.format(i),'taj{0}value'.format(i)))

outfilename = sample+'_tajD.genes.all'

with open(sample+'_rand0.genes.tajD', 'r') as genes, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile :
    for line in genes :
        line = line.strip().split('\t')
        mastergene = line[0]
        for i in range(10):
            'value{0}'.format(i) = 'dic{0}'.format(i)[mastergene]
        allrand = [value0, value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8, value9]
        avg = numpy.mean(allrand)
        outfile.write(mastergene + '\t' + value0 + '\t' + value1 + '\t' + value2 +'\t' + value3 + '\t' + value4 + '\t' + value5 + '\t' + value6 + '\t' + value7 + '\t' + value8 + '\t' + value9 + '\t' + avg + '\n')
```

Comment: What do you want to get by this line `'dic{0}'.format(i) = dict(itertools.izip('gene{0}key'.format(i),'taj{0}value'.format(i)))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'gene{0}key'.format(i) = []
```

This is a typical antipattern that new coders attempt to use. You want to create ten variables with the names `gene1key`, `gene2key`, `gene3key`, etc. The correct way to do this is to use a list or dictionary, which is then indexed using `i` as the key. The simplest way to rewrite your code so it is syntactically correct is:

```
genekeys = {}
tajvalues = {}
dictionaries = {}

for i in range(10):
    filename = sample+'_rand{0}.genes.tajD'.format(i)
    genekeys[i] = []
    tajvalues[i] = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as data:
        for line in data:
            line = line.strip().split('\t')
            gene, taj = line[0], line[3]
            genekeys[i].append(gene)
            tajvalues[i].append(taj)
    dictionaries[i] = dict(itertools.izip(genekeys[i],tajvalues[i]))


with open(sample+'_rand0.genes.tajD', 'r') as genes, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile :
    for line in genes :
        values = {}
        line = line.strip().split('\t')
        mastergene = line[0]
        for i in range(10):
            values[i] = dictionaries[i][mastergene]
        allrand = [values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4], values[5], values[6], values[7], values[8], values[9]]
        avg = numpy.mean(allrand)
        outfile.write(mastergene + '\t' + values[0] + '\t' + values[1] + '\t' + values[2] + '\t' + values[3] + '\t' + values[4] + '\t' + values[5] + '\t' + values[6] + '\t' + values[7] + '\t' + values[8] + '\t' + values[9] + '\t' + avg + '\n')
```

The code could be further simplified. For instance, Since genekeys and tajvalues are used only to create `dictionaries`, you can just populate that dict directly without needing to store the intermediary values. you can make `values` a list, so you don't have to explicitly address each one during `numpy.mean` and `outfile.write`.

```
dictionaries = {}
for i in range(10):
    filename = sample+'_rand{0}.genes.tajD'.format(i)
    dictionaries[i] = {}
    with open(filename, 'r') as data:
        for line in data:
            line = line.strip().split('\t')
            gene, taj = line[0], line[3]
            dictionaries[i][gene] = taj

with open(sample+'_rand0.genes.tajD', 'r') as genes, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile :
    for line in genes :
        line = line.strip().split('\t')
        mastergene = line[0]
        values = []
        for i in range(10):
            values.append(dictionaries[i][mastergene])
        #alternative to the above for loop: values = [dictionaries[i][mastergene] for i in range 10]
        avg = numpy.mean(values)
        outfile.write(mastergene + '\t' + '\t'.join(values) + '\t' + avg + '\n')
```

Comment: Why use `dictionaries = {}` for keys from `range(10)` -> It's a list!

Comment: Thank you! This works (with the exception of the avg which has to do with my files not the code). I really appreciate your explanations - clears up a lot of the issues I was having. Just to make sure I am understanding this - is "dictionaries" a dictionary of the indexed dictionaries? I found that by changing dictionaries = {} to dictionaries = [] (as suggested in the above comment) the code no longer works... Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you again! I just revised this code for a new purpose. Your explanation was so helpful that I was able to make modifications for a different project.